# Filter not working proper in react its working only for first time also how to filter true and false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nsxxqp?file=src%2FApp.js
and my local code is here how to filter i don't know i am new for react and JavaScript please help me i don't know how to finish my task.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Product = (props) => {
 const [allButtons, setAllButtons] = useState([]);
 const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
     fetch("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches?limit=100")
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(productsList => {
         setProduct(productsList);
         setAllButtons(productsList);
       });
 }, []);
 const onBtnClick = (e) =>{
     setProduct(product.filter(i=>i.launch_year == e));
 };
 return(
 <div className="container-fluid">
       <div className="row">
         <div className="col-xl-12">
           <h2>SpacesX Launch Programme</h2>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className="row">
         <div className="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
           <div className="inner">
             <p className="bold">Filter</p>
             <div className="col12 launchYear">
               <p className="marg0">Launch Year</p>
               {allButtons.map(productYr => (
                 <button 
                   className="btn btn-primary btnSpacex"
                   key={productYr.launch_year}
                   onClick={(e) => onBtnClick(productYr.launch_year)}
                 >
                   {productYr.launch_year}
                 </button>
               ))}
             </div>
             <div className="clearfix" />
             <div className="col12 launchYear">
               <p className="marg0">Successful Launch</p>
               <button className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">True</button>
               <button className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">False</button>
             </div>
             <div className="clearfix" />
             <div className="col12 launchYear">
               <p className="marg0">Successful Landing</p>
               <button className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">True</button>
               <button className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">False</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div className="col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 items1">
           <div className="row">
             {product.map(product => (
               <div
                 key={product.flight_number}
                 className="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 marginBottom15"
               >
                 <div className="inner">
                   <img
                     src={product.links.mission_patch}
                     className="full-width imgBg"
                     alt={product.mission_name}
                   />
                   <div className="clearfix" />
                   <p className="productName bold margBot5">
                     {product.mission_name} #{product.flight_number}
                   </p>
                   <div className="clearfix" />
                   <p className="bold margBot5">
                     Mission Ids:
                     <ul className="marg0 blueClr">
                       <li>{product.mission_id}</li>
                     </ul>
                   </p>
                   <div className="clearfix" />
                   <p className="bold margBot5">
                     Launch Year:{" "}
                     <span className="normal blueClr">
                       {product.launch_year}
                     </span>
                   </p>
                   <div className="clearfix" />
                   <p className="bold margBot5">
                     Successful Launch:{" "}
                     <span className="normal blueClr">
                       {product.launch_success}
                     </span>
                   </p>
                   <div className="clearfix" />
                   <p className="bold margBot5">
                     Successful Landing:{" "}
                     <span className="normal blueClr">
                       {product.rocket.land_success}
                     </span>
                   </p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             ))}
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
 )
 }
export default Product
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do exactly, but if you do a filter and pass Boolean as a parameter, it will only show the values that are true.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is your `onButtonClick` function. Change it to the following code (instead of product.filter, use allButtons.filter):

```
const onBtnClick = e => {
    setProduct(allButtons.filter(i => i.launch_year == e));
};
```

The problem was that you had all of your products, then when you selected the first button, you set the product to just that button. On the next click, you're trying to filter on just the single product that you selected in the first click. To get around this, you want the filter to always be on the allButtons list (I'm assuming this was just a small oversight on your part, it looks like you knew exactly what you were trying to do but just accidentally put the wrong list in the function).

Another small change that I would make to your code is below: (introduce index parameter and use it as the key):

```
{allButtons.map((productYr, index) => (
    <button
        className="btn btn-primary btnSpacex"
        key={index}
        onClick={e => onBtnClick(productYr.launch_year)}
    >
        {productYr.launch_year}
    </button>
    ))
}
```

This will eliminate all those console warnings that you're getting for having duplicate keys.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your help but currently facing some issue for Successful Landing not working pls help me

Comment: I'm going to need a bit more info, what's going on?

Comment: Hi lbz Successful Launch and Launch Year filter working but Successful Landing filter not working find my code is this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1kgaz7?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: `i.rocket.first_stage.cores` returns a list, so you can't do `i.rocket.first_stage.cores.land_success`. It's going to be pretty messy with your current code to be honest, but you'd probably want to make that whole `setProduct` line something like `setProduct(e ? landSuccess.filter(i => i.rocket.first_stage.cores.every(x => x.land_successful)) : landSuccess.filter(i => i.rocket.first_stage.cores.some(x => !x.land_successful)));` You'd have to decide whether `some` or `any` are actually suitable in your use case, I've just made assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Product = (props) => {
    const [allButtons, setAllButtons] = useState([]);
    const [launchSuccess, launchAllSuccess] = useState([]);
    const [landSuccess, landAllSuccess] = useState([]);
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches?limit=100")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(productsList => {
            setProduct(productsList);
            setAllButtons(productsList);
            launchAllSuccess(productsList);
            landAllSuccess(productsList);
          });
    }, []);
    
    const onBtnClick = e => {
        setProduct(allButtons.filter(i => i.launch_year === e));
    };

    const onBtnLaunchAllSuccess = e =>{
        setProduct(launchSuccess.filter(i => i.launch_success === e));
    }

    const onBtnLandSuccessful = e =>{
        setProduct(landSuccess.filter(i => i.rocket.first_stage.cores[0].land_success === e));
    }

    return(
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xl-12">
              <h2>SpacesX Launch Programme</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
              <div className="inner">
                <p className="bold">Filter</p>
                <div className="col12 launchYear">
                  <p className="marg0">Launch Year</p>
                  {allButtons.map((productYr, index) => (
                        <button
                            className="btn btn-primary btnSpacex"
                            key={index}
                            onClick={e => onBtnClick(productYr.launch_year)}
                        >
                            {productYr.launch_year}
                        </button>
                        ))
                    }

                </div>
                <div className="clearfix" />
                <div className="col12 launchYear">
                  <p className="marg0">Successful Launch</p>
                  <button 
                  onClick={e => onBtnLaunchAllSuccess(true)}
                  className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">True</button>
                  <button 
                  onClick={e => onBtnLaunchAllSuccess(false)} 
                  className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">False</button>
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix" />
                <div className="col12 launchYear">
                  <p className="marg0">Successful Landing</p>
                  <button 
                  onClick={e => onBtnLandSuccessful(true)}
                  className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">True</button>
                  <button 
                  onClick={e => onBtnLandSuccessful(false)}
                  className="btn btn-default btnSpacex">False</button>
                </div>


              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 items1">
              <div className="row">
                {product.map(product => (
                  <div
                    key={product.flight_number}
                    className="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 marginBottom15"
                  >
                    <div className="inner">
                      <img
                        src={product.links.mission_patch}
                        className="full-width imgBg"
                        alt={product.mission_name}
                      />
                      <div className="clearfix" />
                      <p className="productName bold margBot5">
                        {product.mission_name} #{product.flight_number}
                      </p>
                      <div className="clearfix" />
                      <p className="bold margBot5">
                        Mission Ids:
                        <ul className="marg0 blueClr">
                          <li>{product.mission_id}</li>
                        </ul>
                      </p>
                      <div className="clearfix" />
                      <p className="bold margBot5">
                        Launch Year:
                        <span className="normal blueClr">
                          {product.launch_year}
                        </span>
                      </p>
                      <div className="clearfix" />
                      <p className="bold margBot5">
                        Successful Launch:
                        <span className="normal blueClr">
                          {product.launch_success}
                        </span>
                      </p>
                      <div className="clearfix" />
                      <p className="bold margBot5">
                        Successful Landing:
                        <span className="normal blueClr">
                          {product.rocket.first_stage.cores[0].land_success}
                        </span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```